# Definition of $\chi^2$-divergence between probability distributions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, chi-squared

$
% Some definitions
\def\D#1#2{\operatorname{D_{\chi^2}}(#1 \| #2)}
\def\Df#1#2{\operatorname{D}_{f}(#1 \| #2)}
\def\E#1#2{\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}_{#1}}\left[#2\right]}
\def\dee{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}}
\def\var#1{\operatorname{var}(#1)}
$

I'm interested in the $\chi^2$-divergnce, as a way of comparing probability distributions. There are two ways I've seen it defined. Are they equivalent?

Let $P,Q$ be two probability measures on a set $\mathscr X$ with some sigma algebra, and $p,q$ be their densities with respect to some dominating measure denoted $\dee x$.

1. The first definition I've seen is
   $$\D{P}{Q} \equiv \int_{\mathscr X}\frac{(p(x)-q(x))^2}{p(x)}\dee{x}$$
   This definition makes the relationship with the [Chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) clear.
2. The second definition I've seen is
   $$\D{P}{Q} \equiv \E{Q}{{\left(\frac{\dee{P}}{\dee{Q}}-1\right)}^2} = \int_{\mathscr X}{\left(\frac{\dee{P}}{\dee{Q}}-1\right)}^2\dee{Q}$$
   where $\frac{\dee{P}}{\dee{Q}}$ is the RN-derivative of $P$ with respect to $Q$.  This definition is used in the context of defining $\chi^2$ divergence as an [$f$-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence) ($\Df{P}{Q}\equiv\E{Q}{f(\frac{\dee{P}}{\dee{Q}})}$ with $f(t)=(t -1)^2$).

My question is: are these definitions completely identical, or does the fact that the second one makes no mention of a dominating measure mean that it is more general?

Comment: my intuition is that the first definition wouldn't be defined in cases where the densities (with respect to $\mathrm{d}x$) don't exist, but the second one would still hold.  Is this the answer?